# Pass command to the command prompt open via bat file

Tags: python

I want to pass awk command to the command prompt opened from the bat file

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(r"<.bat file path>",shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Above code will open the command prompt, now I want to send the awk command in the opened command prompt.
How can I do it?

Comment: For that you will have to make changes in the batch file to read arguments passed to it.

Comment: I am not allowed to do any changes in the batch file.